# Why can't I post variables using HTTParty?

Tags: ruby, httparty

I'm trying to use HTTParty to manage requests to an API.  These are the instructions from the documentation:

> **url:** https://www.havelockinvestments.com/r/orderbook
>
> **Required Post Variables** symbol: "VTX"
>
> **Return Data**
>
> *status:* Contains 'ok' or 'error'
>
> *message:* Contains error message if applicable
>
> *bids:* Contains Bids array, as price=>amount pairs
>
> *asks:* Contains Asks array, as price=>amount pairs

This is what I'm putting in my Ruby script:

```
require 'httparty'

response = HTTParty.post(
  'https://www.havelockinvestments.com/r/orderbook', 
  :query => { :symbol => "VTX" }
)
```

But I'm getting an error response:

```
{"status":"error","message":"post:symbol is required"}
```

What am I doing wrong here when posting the symbol variable?

The original documentation is at: https://www.havelockinvestments.com/apidoc.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation seems a bit sparse on the HTTParty Github page, but from the examples it looks like you specify the parameters in a hash as a value to the `:body` key in the options for `HTTParty#post`

Like so:

```
response = HTTParty.post('https://www.havelockinvestments.com/r/orderbook', {body: {symbol: "VTX"}})
```